# How to display info on phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin

So I have managed to sort out my connection with XAMPP and sql server in my previous question. I am sorry I am new to programming and working and studying at the same time so most of this I have to self teach with very little guidance.

My next question is when I type in data, for example, my email on the webpage I am creating, it doesn't display on phpMyAdmin? Is there some sort of connection I am missing or something I'm not understanding?

I have created a database called maxipakdb, and within that, I created a table to show data called maxipaktable in phpMyAdmin.

My code is shown below.

```
<?php
/* Database config */
$db_host        = 'localhost';
$db_user        = 'root';
$db_pass        = '';
$db_database    = 'maxipakdb'; 
/* End config */

$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_database);

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {printf("Connect failed: %s\n",      mysqli_connect_error());}

$email = $_POST['email'];

// Perform queries 

mysqli_query("INSERT INTO maxipaktable (`id`,`email`) 
VALUES (NULL,'&email')");


header('Location: success.php');

echo $email;
?>
```

Comment: [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) requires two parameters. It should be `mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO maxipaktable (`id`,`email`) 
VALUES (NULL,'&email')");`

Comment: Or `$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO maxipaktable (`id`,`email`) 
VALUES (NULL,'&email')");` as you are using the OO connection